# Is there a way to change TCP/IP setting of IP v4 via Powershell/batch?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, tcp, windows-7, ipv4

In my home network , I have to set IP address and DNS server. In Office network that settings to be removed .

Daily i am doing this activity manually. Though powershell automate so many things ,I am not finding any cmdlet for this in Windows 7.

I am doing the procedure [manually](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/change-tcp-ip-settings#1TC=windows-7) . Is there any way to solve this using powershell? Even if batch file is there for it , I can use it

Comment: Powershell V4 has some nice cmdlets such as `Set-NetIPAddress`

Comment: Just as an aside if the issue is easily switching network configurations I would suggest [NetSetMan](http://www.netsetman.com/)

Comment: @Micky Balladelli I am having powershell 4 but this is not supported cmdlet in Windows 7 it seems

Comment: There is always WMI http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/powershell-wmi-methods/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a script that I use for that.

```
$wmi = Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -filter "ipenabled = 'true'"
if($wmi.count -eq 1)
{
    $wmi.EnableStatic("10.0.0.2", "255.255.255.0")
    $wmi.SetGateways("10.0.0.1", 1)
    $wmi.SetDNSServerSearchOrder(@("10.0.0.3","10.0.0.4"))
}
```

An an even better option for most situation (especially home networks) is to use DHCP. If you have a wireless router, It should have that option.

Comment: Caveat is that there might be more than one adapter returned... example could be: wireless and lom. Be aware

Comment: Good catch @Matt, this script will need to be adjusted if there are multiple adapters. I made a quick edit after your comment to make it just a little more copy/paste safe.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't PowerShell a bit of overkill?
You can use simple NETSH command from command line.

To check config:

```
netsh interface ip show config
```

To turn on DHCP:

```
netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" source=dhcp
```

To setup static address:

```
netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" source=static addr=192.168.0.100 mask=255.255.255.0 gateway=192.168.0.1
```